# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property ''is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

1> I have kendo grid, and one of the column has a button. I have assigned javascript function to the onclick event of the button. The javascript makes ajax call. But when I click on the button I get error

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property 'DoSomething' is null or undefined, not a Function object

I tried setting onclick to "javascript:DoSomething();" with no luck

2> I would also like to pass "BatchKey" value to the function if possible

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid< BatchDetail>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Bound(p => p.BatchKey);
        col.Bound(p => p.OriginalCost);
        col.Bound(p => p.Status);
        col.Bound(p => p.LastFileName);
        col.Bound(p => p.FileID).ClientTemplate(
            "# if (Status == \"Error\") { #" +
            "<button id=\"btnResolve\" class=\"resolve-button\" onclick=\"DoSomething();\">Resolve</button>" +
            "#}#"
            ).Title("Action");
    })
    .AutoBind(true)
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("GetData", "Detail", new { ID = Model.ID })))
    )
</div>
```

```html
function DoSomething()
{   
    $.ajax({
        url: "www.msn.com",
        success: function (result)
        {
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: `DoSomething` is in some local scope for sure. Don't use `onclick` attributes with strings, but DOM methods to attach handler references.

Comment: @user3862378 don't edit my post, but add to your own if you need to provide more information. Alternatively, just add a comment. :)

Comment: @Vash I don't see any option to reply with code.The comment has very limited options for replying.

Comment: also if the button is inside the grid, and there is no ID for it. How do I get access to the button I clicked inside the DoSomething() function.

Comment: In your edit of my answer you mentioned you're wrapping the function in a `$(function () {` block. Is that still the case? That's the only way for me to reproduce it.

Comment: Just add `this` to get access to the button. See my updated answer. You don't really need to use ID's. You can generate the ID's, but I don't see a way to attach event handlers to all those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The button ID needs to be unique, so you can't use it like that. You can pass BatchKey like this:

```
 col.Bound(p => p.FileID).ClientTemplate(
     "# if (Status == \"Error\") { #" +
         "<button class=\"resolve-button\" onclick=\"DoSomething(this, '#= BatchKey #');\">Resolve</button>" +
      "#}#"
            ).Title("Action");

function DoSomething(button, batchKey)
{   
    $.ajax({
        url: "www.msn.com",
        success: function (result)
        {
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }
    })
}
```

I've tested this on my own grid and it works fine. If it still doesn't work there is an issue with code outside of what you've posted.